# How can I bring text by StringTokenizer

Tags: java, arrays, stringtokenizer

Imagine this array.

```
data[0] = <a href="/item/main.nhn?code=002530" class="tltle">Marine</a>
data[1] = <a href="/item/main.nhn?code=068270" class="tltle">Medic</a>
data[2] = <a href="/item/main.nhn?code=053800" class="tltle">Firebat</a>
```

I want to bring attribute of code (002530, 068270, 053800) to code[] array. 
and pure text (Marine, Medic, Firebat).
Like this:

```
code[0] = 002530
code[1] = 068270
code[2] = 053800
text[0] = Marine
text[1] = Medic
text[2] = Firebat
```

How can I do that? Should I have to use StringTokenizer? or split()? 
I don't know how to get that. Please Help me. Thank you.

Comment: Why not use regular expressions?, something like http://fiddle.re/hvu88 (Click java to run the regex)

Comment: @Avolpe I don't know that. I'm newbie of Java. I'm trying on it to use StringTokenizer. But it's very difficult for me... maybe I have to stay all night...

Comment: @Avolpe How can I use that? I never heard about regular expressions. can you write simple example or full source code? thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions, [See this Voguella tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

```
".*code=([0-9]*).*>([A-Za-z]*)<.*"
```

And a code like this:

```
    String[] array = new String[3];
    array[0] = "<a href=\"/item/main.nhn?code=002530\" class=\"tltle\">Marine</a>";
    array[1] = "<a href=\"/item/main.nhn?code=068270\" class=\"tltle\">Medic</a>";
    array[2] = "<a href=\"/item/main.nhn?code=053800\" class=\"tltle\">Firebat</a>";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*code=([0-9]*).*>([A-Za-z]*)<.*");

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        String string = array[i];
        Matcher ma = pattern.matcher(string);
        System.out.println("Code " + i + ":" + ma.replaceFirst("$1"));
        System.out.println("Text " + i + ":" + ma.replaceFirst("$2"));
    }
```

see a working example in: http://ideone.com/WJIjM5

Obs: remember to escape " in your strings.

Comment: Very Very Very Thank you. I really impressed...T.T

Comment: sure, if you want help, please send me a email, (see my profile). Cheers and good lunk with your sc program!

Comment: Can I ask one more question please? `<a href="/item/main.nhn?code=002530" class="tltle">Marine</a>` is my code. but you show me `<a href=\"/item/main.nhn?code=002530\ class=\"tltle\">Marine</a>` **The diffrence of two is back-slash.** I can't apply to my code.. T.T Can you help me...?

Comment: Can you show me a example of the response?, I dont see anything wrong with your code. You can use pastebin or send directly to my mail. Cheers

Comment: The problem is with the letters, jsoup don't parse it correctly. Change the regular expression to ".*code=([0-9]*).*>(.*)<.*" and try again.

Comment: it's work! Thank you so much.!!! I'm really really happy. Hava a good chirstmas ! Thank you!!